# What's the type of element from a array consisted of some subclass instance?

Tags: swift

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/typecasting/#Defining-a-Class-Hierarchy-for-Type-Casting

```
class MediaItem {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Movie: MediaItem {
    var director: String
    init(name: String, director: String) {
        self.director = director
        super.init(name: name)
    }
}

class Song: MediaItem {
    var artist: String
    init(name: String, artist: String) {
        self.artist = artist
        super.init(name: name)
    }
}

let library = [
    Movie(name: "Casablanca", director: "Michael Curtiz"),
    Song(name: "Blue Suede Shoes", artist: "Elvis Presley"),
    Movie(name: "Citizen Kane", director: "Orson Welles"),
    Song(name: "The One And Only", artist: "Chesney Hawkes"),
    Song(name: "Never Gonna Give You Up", artist: "Rick Astley")
]
```

In case, said that, "However, if you iterate over the contents of this array, the items you receive back are typed as MediaItem, and not as Movie or Song.", however I run the code below,

`for item in library { print(type(of: item)) }`

Output:

`Movie Song Movie Song Song`

It‘s confusing !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is confusing... and here is the reason.

Looking at the code:

```
class MediaItem {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Movie: MediaItem {
    var director: String
    init(name: String, director: String) {
        self.director = director
        super.init(name: name)
    }
}


class Song: MediaItem {
    var artist: String
    init(name: String, artist: String) {
        self.artist = artist
        super.init(name: name)
    }
}

let library = [
    Movie(name: "Casablanca", director: "Michael Curtiz"),
    Song(name: "Blue Suede Shoes", artist: "Elvis Presley"),
    Movie(name: "Citizen Kane", director: "Orson Welles"),
    Song(name: "The One And Only", artist: "Chesney Hawkes"),
    Song(name: "Never Gonna Give You Up", artist: "Rick Astley")
]
// the type of "library" is inferred to be [MediaItem]

for item in library {
    print(type(of: item))
}
```

You have to make the distinction between what the Swift compiler knows at compile time and what is known at run time.

The Swift compiler can't know the contents of the array.  So all the Swift compiler knows is that the item selected from the array is a `MediaItem`.

`print(type(of: item))` is operating at run time.  At run time, the actual type of the item is known and so `print(type(of: item))` prints out the actual type.

But here's the problem, you have to convince the Swift compiler of the type (`Movie` or `Song`) before you can operate on the underlying type.  That is where the conditional casting comes in:

```
for item in library {
    if let movie = item as? Movie {
        print("Movie: \(movie.name), dir. \(movie.director)")
    } else if let song = item as? Song {
        print("Song: \(song.name), by \(song.artist)")
    }
}
```

When you option-click on `item`, Xcode will tell you it is `let item: MediaItem`.  When you option-click on `movie`, Xcode will tell you it is `let movie: Movie`.  When you option-click on `song`, Xcode will tell you it is `let song: Song`.

Xcode is showing you what the Swift compiler knows at compile time.  These are the types that determine which methods and properties can be called/accessed by the code.

So the statement:

> However, if you iterate over the contents of this array, the items
> you receive back are typed as MediaItem, and not as Movie or Song.

is talking about what is known by Swift at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

`library` is a mixed bag, but an array can have only *one* type of element in Swift. Therefore the compiler *infers* the type to the common denominator, namely MediaItem, and every item of the array is seen as a MediaItem *by the compiler, as you work on your code*.

But when you iterate though the array and print *at runtime*, you are interrogating the *individual objects* which exist at runtime. *At runtime*, an *actual object* has a fixed type and *knows* what that type is, and that is what you are asking for and printing.

Please note that code like this is not a good idea:

```
let library = [
    Movie(name: "Casablanca", director: "Michael Curtiz"),
    Song(name: "Blue Suede Shoes", artist: "Elvis Presley"),
    Movie(name: "Citizen Kane", director: "Orson Welles"),
    Song(name: "The One And Only", artist: "Chesney Hawkes"),
    Song(name: "Never Gonna Give You Up", artist: "Rick Astley")
]
```

You should not force the compiler to waste time inferring the common
denominator. Under some circumstances, this will be considered an error on your part. Instead, *you* should do the inferring:

```
let library: [MediaItem] = [
    Movie(name: "Casablanca", director: "Michael Curtiz"),
    Song(name: "Blue Suede Shoes", artist: "Elvis Presley"),
    Movie(name: "Citizen Kane", director: "Orson Welles"),
    Song(name: "The One And Only", artist: "Chesney Hawkes"),
    Song(name: "Never Gonna Give You Up", artist: "Rick Astley")
]
```